# Static initializer on a inner class?

Tags: java

How to allow static initializer on a inner class like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    public class InnerClass {
        static {
            // do something
        }
        public bar(){
            // do something
        }
    }

    // method stuff
    public void foo() {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [JLS 8.1.3 Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.1.3):

> Inner classes may not declare static initializers (§8.7) or member interfaces.

What you may want is a *nested* class:

```
public static class InnerClass { // note "static"
```

Comment: In my experience, in about 80% of the time, a nested class is what people wanted to define anyway. In this case the minimum number of keywords is hurting Java; as a language designer you might want to make the nested classes the default and have an "inner" keyword for the inner classes.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define the `InnerClass` class as static. But, thereafter, it won't be a regular inner class.

Comment: This is ok in my case since my "inner" class is not going to access the enclosing class methods at all. Actually I could have crated a separate .java class file however since the class will only be accessed on the the said enclosing class, then I decided to just enclose the class.

Answer (score 1):

As it's already stated by @yshavit you can't declare static initializers, but from what I found you can get around that by declaring a method to do any initializations you want and simply call it when defining your class' fields. For example I implemented this iterator (this is an anonymous inner class) :

```
public Iterator<String> iterator() {

    return new Iterator<String>() {

        int someField = initializeIterator();

        // Keeps current position in the list of direct neighboring out

        private int initializeIterator() {
            // Do your initializations 
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            //hasNext implementation
        }

        @Override
        public Vertex next() { 
            //next implementation
         } 
         //...
```

This feels very hack-y and I wonder If I'm missing something but this totally works and the initialization method is only called once just like a static initialization block would be...